# Inheritance and private variables

Tags: java, inheritance, extend

In the HourlyEmployee and SalariedEmployee sub-classes we call `super()` to pass "name" to the base class constructor. I have two questions:

1. Where does the variable name come from, is this a typo for the aName variable?
2. How does calling `setSalary()` work in those sub-classes?

Does extending the Employee class gives us a copy of the `setSalary()` method but then inside the method there is `aSalary=salary;` where salary is not inherited because it is private OR does inheritance simply let us use the `setSalary()` method from the base class which is why using `super()` to pass the name would make sense.

```
public class Employee {
  private String name;
  private double salary;

  public Employee(String aName) {
     name = aName; 
  }

  public void setSalary(double aSalary) {
     salary = aSalary; 
  }

  public String getName() {
     return name; 
  }

  public double getSalary() {
     return salary; 
  }

  public double getWeeklySalary() {
     return salary/52; 
  }
}

public class HourlyEmployee extends Employee {
    public HourlyEmployee(String aName, double anHourlySalary) {
        super(name);
        setSalary(anHourlySalary*40*52);
    }
}

public class SalariedEmployee extends Employee {
    public SalariedEmployee(String aName, double anAnnualSalary) {
        super(name);
        setSalary(anAnnualSalary);
    }
}
```

Comment: you did not pass anything with super(name). You should pass super(aName).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Where does the variable name come from, is this a typo for the `aName` variable ?

   Yes, it's a typo. Should be `aName`, otherwise it won't compile.
2. How does calling `setSalary()` work in those sub-classes ?

   When extending a class, the subclass inherits all of the functionality in the superclass. This is why the `SalariedEmployee` and `HourlyEmployee` classes have *access* to the `setSalary()` method: they both inherit the functionality from the `Employee` class.

   You should note that the subclasses don't access the `salary` field directly, but via the `setSalary()` and the `getSalary()` methods. This is called **encapsulation** and it's used to restrict the direct access to the class members.

Comment: So getSalary() IS able to access the private variables that were inherited but not normally accessible? The getSalary() that is inherited returns the salary variable, this is okay?

Comment: The `getSalary()` is able to access the private members, because it's defined within the same class. And yes, the `getSalary()` returns the value of the `salary` member even in the subclasses. :)

Answer (score 1):

1. public Employee(String aName) is public, so you can invoke it from extending class
2. private fields and method are inherited from extended classes, but they are not accesible from it. If you use a debugger you can see that private fields are part of inherited class, but you have no visibility.